# Doctrine OneToOne identity through foreign entity exception on flush

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have `User` and `UserProfile` OneToOne–related Doctrine ORM entities. They should always exist as a pair, there should be no `User` without `UserProfile`.

User should get its id from autoincrement, while UserProfile should have User's id. So they both should have the same id and there is no other column to set up the relationship ([Doctrine docs: Identity through foreign Entities](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities)).

UserProfile's id is both a primary key (PK) and foreign key (FK) at the same time.

I managed to set it up, but it requires that User is saved first and only later UserProfile is created and saved in a separate step.

What I want is that UserProfile is always created with User, in the constructor, but if I do that, I get this exception:

`Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: The given entity of type 'AppBundle\Entity\UserProfile' (AppBundle\Entity\UserProfile@0000000052e1b1eb00000000409c6f2c) has no identity/no id values set. It cannot be added to the identity map.`

Please see code below – it works, but not the way I want. The php comments show what I want to achieve.

`Test.php`:

```
/**
 * It works, both saving and loading.
 * BUT, it requires that I create and save UserProfile 
 * in a separate step than saving User step.
 */

// create and save User
$user = new User();
$objectManager->persist($user);
$objectManager->flush();

// create and save UserProfile (this should be unnecessary)
$user->createProfile()
$objectManager->flush();
```

`User.php`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="uid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * It's NULL at first, I create it later (after saving User).
     * 
     * @var UserProfile|null
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserProfile", mappedBy="user", cascade="persist")
     */
    private $profile = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // I want to create UserProfile inside User's constructor,
        // so that it is always present (never NULL):
        //$this->profile = new UserProfile($this);

        // but this would give me error:
        //
        // Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: 
        // The given entity of type 'AppBundle\Entity\UserProfile' 
        // (AppBundle\Entity\UserProfile@0000000058af220a0000000079dc875a)
        // has no identity/no id values set. It cannot be added to the identity map.
    }

    public function createProfile()
    {
        $this->profile = new UserProfile($this);
    }   
}
```

`UserProfile.php`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="profiles")
 */
class UserProfile
{
    /**
     * – UserProfile's "uid" column points to User's "uid" column
     * – it is PK (primary key)
     * - it is FK (foreign key) as well
     * – "owning side"
     *
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profile")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="uid", referencedColumnName="uid", nullable=false)
    */
    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }    
}
```

Test app: https://github.com/MacDada/DoctrineOneToOneTest

Comment: Id is a database thing and should not be a concern in your model.  Give up the notion that they need the same primary key value.  Or failing that, generate give up the notion that one needs to be auto and the other does not.

Comment: @Cerad I'm building upon a legacy app – the database is what it is. I need to adjust Doctrine to the current schema, not vice versa…

Plus, the code above works. Doctrine can handle foreign keys being primary keys. It just cannot persist the entities in one flush. Or at least I'm looking for the answer, how to configure Doctrine so that it can.

Comment: Fair enough.  If you do a search then you will find several hundred variations of this same question.  All with the same answer.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143812/doctrine2-3-and-onetoone-cascade-persist-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: Looks like you need to change the owning side of relationship.

Comment: @JakubZalas It works but it also adds  `profile_id` column to User's table instead of just using `uid` column. It's unnecessary (from the database POV) and requires to change the db schema plus (what's worse) the existing app. https://github.com/MacDada/DoctrineOneToOneTest/tree/zalas

Comment: Perhaps you've put the JoinColumn annotation on the wrong side?

Comment: Example on [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity).

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that the actual object needs to be saved by the EntityManager.
Just giving the class as reference to the other class does not make the entityManager aware of the fact both classes exists.

You should persist the actual userProfile to the EntityManager to be able to save the relation.

UPDATE because of negative comment:

Please read the Doctrine docs... You should persist!

The following example is an extension to the User-Comment example of this chapter. Suppose in our application a user is created whenever he writes his first comment. In this case we would use the following code:

```
<?php
$user = new User();
$myFirstComment = new Comment();
$user->addComment($myFirstComment);

$em->persist($user);
$em->persist($myFirstComment);
$em->flush();
```

Even if you persist a new User that contains our new Comment this code would fail if you removed the call to EntityManager#persist($myFirstComment). Doctrine 2 does not cascade the persist operation to all nested entities that are new as well.

**Update2:**
I understand what it is you wish to accomplish, but by design you should not move this logic within your entities. Entities should represent as less logic as possible, since they represent your modal.

Have that said, I believe you could accomplish what you are trying to do like this:

```
$user = new User();
$profile = $user->getProfile();
$objectManager->persist($user);
$objectManager->persist($profile);
$objectManager->flush();
```

You should however consider creating a userService containing the entitymanager and make that responsible for creating, linking and persisting the user + userProfile entity.

Comment: Nope, the profile is matched to be persisted thanks to `cascade="persist"`. If I remove it and persist the profile "by hand", the problem still remains.

Comment: It doesn't help, I've already tried that (even one more time, right now, to be completely sure). Same error.

Comment: `./app/console cache:clear && sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart && sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart && sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart && ./app/console cache:clear`

Comment: Could you share how you tried to do the seperate persist?

Comment: See the repo: https://github.com/MacDada/DoctrineOneToOneTest/tree/manual_persist1 The test is here: https://github.com/MacDada/DoctrineOneToOneTest/blob/manual_persist1/src/AppBundle/Tests/UserAndProfilePersistanceTest.php

Comment: Without to want to sound like an ass:
You request the profile here: $profile = $user->getProfile();

And insert $this to the UserProfile.

However, $this has not yet been saved so the relationship can not be determined. Best would be to create a SOA and create the user in a service method, (And don't do magic in the methods of the entity) make sure the entities are known by the EM on their own and then linked in the service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78580/discussion-between-macdada-and-armand).