# Symfony: The given entity of type cannot be added to the identity map

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am getting the following exception whilst trying to persist a entity and associative entity to the database. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here:

Exception:

```
The given entity of type 'AppBundle\Entity\User' 
(AppBundle\Entity\User@0000000065c3019f00000000123d7c75) has no 
identity/no id values set. It cannot be added to the identity map.
```

Entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
protected $address;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address
{
 /**
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  */
 private $id

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="address", cascade={"all"}, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $user;
}
```

Entity creation:

```
$user = new User();
$address = new Address();
$address->setUser($user->setAddress($address));

$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($user);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($address);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

Comment: Your posted code does not seem to show User::id?

Comment: User::address is both the primary key and the foreign key.

Comment: That won't work.  Each Doctrine entity needs an explicit id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine OneToOne identity through foreign entity exception on flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402203/doctrine-onetoone-identity-through-foreign-entity-exception-on-flush)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see: [Doctrine OneToOne identity through foreign entity exception on flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402203/doctrine-onetoone-identity-through-foreign-entity-exception-on-flush) which helped to resolve this issue.

The actual object address needs to be saved by the EntityManager first. Just giving the class as reference to the other class does not make the entityManager aware of the fact both classes exists. With this in mind, the following code allows me to persist these objects to the database. I belive this is because doctrine needs to persist the address object first, so that it can retrieve the id for the primary & foreign key relationship in the User object.

```
$user = new User();
$address = new Address();

$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($address);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

$address->setUser($user->setAddress($address));

$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($user);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

Answer (score -3):

You MUST specify an ID for doctrine entity

like this:

```
class User
{
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string") 
    */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\Id
    */
    protected $address;
}
```